# create a simple function for calculating root mean square error using data Seq[Seq[(Double,Double]]

Tags: scala

I need to create a simple function for calculating Root Mean Square Error using `Seq[Seq[(Double,Double)]]` as the input:

This is my attempt:

```
  val getRMSE: (Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]) => Double = {
    (predictions) =>
      val mse = predictions
        .map {
          case (rating, prediction) =>
            val err = rating-prediction
            err*err
        }.mean()
      math.sqrt(mse)
  }
```

The question is how to resolve the compilation error with `err*err` and `rating-prediction`. It says "Cannot resolve symbol *"

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul: Thanks for noticing. I have accidentally deleted the question itself:) See my update.

Comment: Hmm. Tha's not the error I get.  `predictions` is a `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)`. So each element of the map is a `Seq[(Double,Double)]` and that doesn't match your case of a `(Double, Double)`. So the logic of the code is a little confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your `predictions` is actually `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]`. So when you call `map` on it you have to provide a function which takes parameter of type `Seq[(Double, Double)]`, but you pass a function from `(Double, Double)`.

```
case (rating, prediction)
```

is wrong, change it to

```
case seqOfPairs: Seq[(Double, Double)] //actually ((Double, Double) is erased in compile time)
```

I hope this will get you on the right way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is what I wrote based on your answer, however I still cannot figure out how to add `mean`. Now it's marked in red by the compiler: `val mse = output
        .map {
          case seqOfPairs: Seq[(Double, Double)] =>
            val err = seqOfPairs.map(p => math.abs(p._1 - p._2)).sum
            err*err
        }.mean
      math.sqrt(mse)`

Comment: also, where is your `mean` defined?

Comment: How to correctly add `mean`? I now added it at the end of `seqOfPairs.map{}.mean`

Comment: mean is not defined on `Seq` class. You can't use method, which is not defined

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that it's not define. Thanks.